# Unable to get only price from WorldCoin Index API

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm using the world coin index API, however when using the following with google scripts:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.worldcoinindex.com/apiservice/ticker?key=h3mWeJn5YvaCFGIVqGGXz4fuKM9EaA&label=sumobtc&fiat=btc");
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  sheet.getRange(2,10).setValue([data.Markets.Price]);
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

I'm getting the following response

```
`{"Markets":[{"Label":"SUMO/BTC","Name":"Sumokoin","Price":0.00028270,"Volume_24h":15.68123925,"Timestamp":1525166340}]}`
```

I'm trying to get the individual Price only and not the total information

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your response contains an *array* of objects on the `Market` key. If you would like to access the first price in this array of objects, you must first access the first index of the array, then access the price key of this object.

You should be able to access this value with `data.Markets[0].Price`